# Exim4 e-mails not going out

Tags: ubuntu, email, smtp

I'm running a Ubuntu VPS (running 20.04.6 LTS), on which I have installed exim4. I want to use exim to send some e-mails from a PHP application I have running on this server. I am not interested in receiving e-mails on this server (there are no MX-records pointing to this server for receiving mail).

When I try to send a mail, either through the commandline or the application, no mail is sent and the following appears in `/var/log/exim4/mainlog`:

```
2023-08-22 20:01:43 1qYXZP-00AlXT-0B <= <REDACTED> U=<REDACTED> P=local S=300
2023-08-22 20:01:43 Warning: No server certificate defined; will use a selfsigned one.
 Suggested action: either install a certificate or change tls_advertise_hosts option
2023-08-22 20:03:53 1qYXZP-00AlXT-0B H=reception.mail-tester.com [94.23.206.89]: SMTP timeout after initial connection: Connection timed out
2023-08-22 20:03:53 1qYXZP-00AlXT-0B == test-ble2rad33@srv1.mail-tester.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out H=reception.mail-tester.com [94.23.206.89]: SMTP timeout after initial connection
```

#### Potentially relevant information:

The VPS host I'm using has a firewall to which I can add ingress and egress rules. I tried looking for information about what ports exim4 uses for outgoing connections, but I couldn't find anything. The only thing I found that seemed relevant was someone suggesting it communicates over high "unprivileged" ports as opposed to low "privileged" ports which implied to me that the ports it communicates over are generally not subject to (outgoing) security rules.

The domain I'm using in the e-mail's From-header has the server's ip listed in its SPF-record.

#### My question

Is there a way to debug this properly? Is it something as simple as setting up the proper egress rules for my firewall, or do I need to do something else?

Disclaimer: I realize that e-mail is generally something left to the professionals, nothing mission critical is going on here and if it doesn't work it doesn't work. This is purely because I'd like to learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried looking for information about what ports exim4 uses for outgoing connections, but I couldn't find anything.

SMTP mail exchange between domains (MX service) always uses the standard SMTP port 25 (TCP).

This is not Exim4-specific – if you're running a mail server, it will accept inbound mail at port 25 on your side, and it will deliver outbound mail to port 25 on the recipient's MX servers.

One easy way to find out what ports a given program is trying to use is through a *packet capture* tool such as `tcpdump` or `tshark`, which shows you what's going in and out over your network interface. If exim4 tries to make a TCP connection to some server, you'd literally see a TCP SYN packet in tcpdump's output, with the IP addresses and ports written down.

These days in 2023 **most cloud-hosting services block port 25** due to how many of their "customers" are quick to spin up tons of VMs with dubious funds in order to send out spam from them. So now your cloud-host has a hidden firewall rule that blocks TCP port 25 in both directions.

Depending on the hosting service you're using, it might be enough to ask nicely for SMTP to be unblocked; the process might be documented on their website; or they might tell you to use a third-party mail sending API instead.

> The only thing I found that seemed relevant was someone suggesting it communicates over high "unprivileged" ports as opposed to low "privileged" ports which implied to me that the ports it communicates over are generally not subject to (outgoing) security rules.

Well, kind of, but not exactly.

Every TCP connection has **two** ports (one on each end); usually the port on the client side will be chosen randomly from the high "ephemeral" range.

For example, when your browser connects to the HTTPS service at superuser.com "on port 443", the initial packet goes *from* an ephemeral port on your side *to* port 443 to the web server's side. When a reply arrives from the web server, it will be from the server's port 443 to the ephemeral port on your machine.

(The replies do bypass firewalls, but not because they're sent to an ephemeral port – rather, because a stateful firewall *remembers* what host:ports you're communicating with. Note that this isn't always the case for cloud-hosting firewalls; they could often be stateless.)

"Privileged" vs "unprivileged" has nothing to do with firewalls, by the way – it's only about the traditional Unix-specific restriction that only services running as root may *receive* connections into a privileged port (under 1024).

> The domain I'm using in the e-mail's From-header has the server's ip listed in its SPF-record.

The "Connection timed out" message implies Exim4 wasn't able to connect at all, so it never got to the point where SPF checks would be done (as the recipient server doesn't yet know *which domain's* SPF it would need to check). SPF failures would either cause a SMTP-level rejection message to show up instead (with the 3-digit error code) or would cause the mail to be accepted but trashed.

Keep in mind that there are *two* "From" addresses; one in the email headers and another in the SMTP envelope (which the recipient might see as "Return-Path" header). SPF is mostly about the latter.

> I am not interested in receiving e-mails on this server (there are no MX-records pointing to this server for receiving mail).

You'll want to change that, as because of the aforementioned spam issue, the spam filters at most recipients will look at your domain a bit funny if it has no MX records at all.

So it's not about being able to receive mail (you *can* receive mail without explicit MX records – the server itself becomes an implicit MX per the standard) but about indicating to others that you're a Legitimate Operation and not just a random webhost that got hacked.

While in theory your SPF record should trump the lack of MX (as it is much more explicit about what it means), in practice many filters will check for MX anyway (possibly even rejecting your mail before they check SPF).

(And, to be honest, you *should* want to receive mail to abuse@, at least in theory.)

Comment: Your post led me to try to specify the outgoing *destination* port as an egress rule. This seems to me like a stupidly obvious thing to try, but for some reason I did not. It works now, and the mails are being received so I'm marking this as the answer.

Also, the specific domain these mails are being sent from does have an MX-record, there just isn't an MX-record pointing to this specific server (the "regular" mail is being handled by a 3rd party e-mail provider).